# combine items of two lists

Tags: linq

I want to combine items of two string list but do not want repeated items

```
List<string> l1 = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D"};
List<string> l2 = new List<string>() { "B", "E", "G", "D"};
```

Result: A, B, C, D, E, G

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Union` and `Distinct` operators:

```
var newList = l1.Union(l2).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ to produce the union of the two lists:

```
var combined = l1.Union(l2);
```

Comment: It won't, as it is defined as set union. From MSDN documentation: `This method excludes duplicates from the return set. This is different behavior to the Concat<(Of <(TSource>)>) method, which returns all the elements in the input sequences including duplicates.`

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Not quite as elegant as the above answer.

```
        List<string> l1 = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
        List<string> l2 = new List<string>() { "B", "E", "G", "D" };

        l1.Concat(l2);
        IEnumerable<string> noDupes = l1.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

C# 2.0 version

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
l1.AddRange(l2);
foreach(string s in l1) dict[s] = s;
List<string> result = new List<string>(dict.Values);
```